# how to run shell command inside awk

Tags: shell, awk, pwd

i am trying to change dir when from A path to B path like below

```
pwd|awk '{if($1=="/") cd /tmp/}'
awk: syntax error near line 1
awk: illegal statement near line 1
```

please suggest

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calling `cd` from within `awk` is possible (using `system()`, there is no `awk` command that is called `cd`), but wouldn't do much.  In particular, it would not change the current working directory of the shell that started `awk`. The working directory is local to an environment, and `awk` and any other process or subshell are running in their own environments, inherited from their parent processes (and the parent process' environment can't be changed from a child process).

If you just want to see whether the current directory is the root directory and `cd` to `/tmp` if it is, then you may do so in the shell directly:

```
[ "$PWD" = "/" ] && cd /tmp
```

Comment: Strictly speaking the OP's code would also attempt to `cd /tmp` when `$PWD` is `"/ dir with spaces/there"` or `$'/tmp/a\n/\n/b'`...

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Yes, due to the way `awk` would split the line. I don't think that was the intention though.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `system()` in `awk` to run any command, but you cannot use it to change directory as it runs the command in a subshell, so that you will change directory in the subshell which will immediately exit. The command would be as follows:

```
pwd|awk '$0 == "/"{system("cd /tmp")}'
```

But as I said it will not work. If you add `echo` in front of the command you can see it is in fact running when you'd expect it too:

```
$ cd /
$ pwd|awk '$0 == "/"{system("echo cd /tmp")}'
cd /tmp
$ cd /home
$ pwd|awk '$0 == "/"{system("echo cd /tmp")}'
```

I think it would be better to just use and `if` statement:

```
if [ "${PWD}" = '/' ];then 
  cd /tmp
fi
```